# Why All my Local html files URLs redirect me to one URL

Tags: html, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

Good Evening everyOne, i'm trying to make a web app using Spring boot and Thymeleaf. my problem is that all the redirect links in my index html file send me to one link which is my Login.html file.

this is my cotroller :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/signuo")
public String signup() {
    return "signup";
}
}
```

Login and SignUp page. (they are not complete, its just a test)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th = "http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SignUp</title>
</head>
<body>
         <h1>This is the SignUp page</h1>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th = "http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
         <h1>This is the Login page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the index page is so long : i'm gonna give you the important parts

```
"Stuuuf here ... "

<a th:href="@{/index.html}" class="nav-brand"><img src="img/core-img/agri_en_logo.png" alt="" /></a>

 ..... 

<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a th:href="@{/index}">Acceuil</a></li>      
<li><a href="#">Onca</a></li>      
<li><a href="#">ONICL</a></li>            
<li><a href="#">IAV</a></li>
</ul>
<ul><li><a th:href="@{/login}">S'inscrire</a></li></ul>

................ 

<div class="header-add-area">
      <a th:href = "@{/signup}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn newsbox-btn 100">S'authentifier</button>
        </a>
```

this is the hierarchy of my project :

[hierarchy of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYm6o.png)

if you need something else add it in comments, if you need also my hole project i can send it to you in private. 
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: do you implement spring security no your project?

Comment: Whatever security framework you are using is redirecting you to the login page coz you are not authenticated. Either authenticate, configure the framework however you want or just remove it.

Comment: Yes i'm using Spring Security FrameWork , should i remove the configuration or just do some modifications ?